# Passenger Standalone vs Unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger, unicorn

Can someone please compare and contrast Passenger Standalone (formerly Passenger Lite) and Unicorn. I am strictly asking about Passenger Standalone, not the Apache module or Nginx module version most people use.

So far I know: Passenger Standalone can serve "slow clients" directly.

Thanks!

Comment: Passenger Standalone is Nginx with passenger module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to go with Unicorn because it is built for the proxy model. I imagine that if any differences exist between Unicorn and Passenger Standalone, that Unicorn would be designed to be optimized to be used through a proxy.

Comment: Phusion Passenger Standalone is also designed to be used through a proxy and fares just as well. Difference is, Unicorn has its own HTTP parser while Phusion Passenger Standalone uses a fast Nginx core and thus inherits all its features.